# Injecting jQuery to TypeScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I have a controller in my angularjs application, named `AppController`. I'm trying to inject jQuery in the constructor of my class, and the problem is that it doesn't let me use the functions defined in jQuery:

```
module bandar {
  'use strict';

  export class AppController {
    $: jQuery;
    constructor ($: jQuery) {
      this.$ = $;
    }
    goToTab(tabName){
      this.$("[role='tab']").tab('show');
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the proper way of doing it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be referencing the jquery.d.ts up top like this:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

Here's an example from the typescript site: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/jquery

Comment: But there are some compile errors when I try to compile `jquery.d.ts` file.

Comment: You shouldn't be compiling your definition files

Comment: @Masious what version of typescript are you using? And what do the errors from the definition file look like? You might be using an older version of typescript that doesn't support certain language features in the definition file.